# Where to make source code publically available

Tags: silverlight

I've just finished a mini-project (a graphical 2d [silverlight tag cloud](http://blog.figmentengine.com/search/label/tag%20cloud)) and I've made the source code available on my website as a zip file - but where should I put the code to allow people to find it and evolve it if they wish? codeplex? but I guess this would count as an inactive project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend github.

Comment: at what point do I decide to put it on something like github?, otherwise these repositories will be full of pet projects that are not that interesting..

Comment: Use it as soon as you start writing. git's a good SCM. Let others (google included) decide if it's interesting or not.

Answer (score 3):

http://sourceforge.net/

Find and Build
Open Source Software

Answer (score 2):

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) is great, free, and easy. It supports subversion.

Comment: vote +1 for google code. github has limited to Git and free 100mb space only ;)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeplex.com/ This is run by Microsoft, which should be a fine match with Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

CodeProject is good too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what you plan to do.

- If you want to share the code with the world and open it to large cooperation, definitely go [github](http://github.com/)
- If you want to setup a nice web site, with a complete community with mailing lists, and a selected number of authorized contributors, go [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net).
- Alternatively, you could use one of the sourceforge-like : google code, codeplex, savannah, berlios...